# How to display varBinary field data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a database field whose dataType is varBinary. Now in a gridView I want to display that data. But i am getting output:

```
System.Byte[]
```

not the value

```
0x2C6D1A
```

which is in the database.

Please help how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class to format your byte array for display purposes:

```
string forDisplay =
    "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(yourByteArray).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

If you don't want to convert directly to a `string`, then [`BitConverter` has a load of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter_members.aspx) for converting from byte arrays to various other types.

**EDIT...**

If you're binding some query results directly to the `GridView` control then it might be easier to convert your `VARBINARY` column to a `VARCHAR` in the query itself:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), your_varbinary_column, 1) AS for_display
FROM your_table
```

*(Note: This type of conversion - from `VARBINARY` to `VARCHAR` in `'0x1234AB'` format - only works correctly in SQL Server 2008. Earlier versions of SQL Server just cast the binary data directly to character data.)*

Comment: Can you please be little more specific. I am sorry I couldnt understand where to add this line of code: 

`string forDisplay =
    "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(yourByteArray).Replace("-", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't anything obvious available, perhaps just loop:

```
    public static string ToHexString(byte[] raw)
    { // could also be an extension method
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("0x", 2 + (raw.Length * 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(raw[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

If this is a class property, it would be trivial to create a `TypeConverter` that does this (for display purposes), and mark the property with `[TypeConverter(typeof(HexConverter))]`:

```
    class HexConverter : TypeConverter // untested
    {
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
            object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return ToHexString((byte[])value);
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the best way to bind data from sql server to datagrid? I need to give users option to update a file (replace an existing file with new file), do I need to first load the existing file from the sql server and then give option to users to replace it or can it be replaced without loading it into the webapplication ?

Comment: @RehanMehdi that seems a completely unrelated question; I would just throw it into an object model...

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you help me in writing that. I am new to object programming. Should I start a new question with my code on it?

Comment: @Rehan that does not sound like a very specific question... you can try, but to be well received it would need to be a little more specific than that.